# Question about tensors

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, index-notation

In general, which is the difference between this tensors: $T_{ij}$ and $T^{ij}$? For the metric, $g_{ij}=\vec{e}_{i}\cdot \vec{e}_{j}$, why $g^{ij}$ is as simple as its inverse matrix?

So, given a general tensor $T_{ij}$ in its matricial form, how can I find the tensor $T^{ij}$ also in its matricial form?

An example would be the following. Given this metric, $g_{ij}(\mu,\nu)$ 
[Metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4pUA.png)
ant this tensor $R_{ij}(\mu, \nu)$, the Ricci tensor, 
[Ricci tensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAQph.png)
how can I find the tensor $R^{ij}$ using matrix notation?

Comment: $(g^{i,j})$ is **defined** to be the inverse matrix of $(g_{i,j})$. If you have a tensor $(T_{i,j})$, then $T^{i,j}$ is **defined** to be $T_{k,l}g^{k,i}g^{l,j}$, summing over repeatd indices. I don't know what a "matricial form" is... If you explained exactly what you want, it would probably be useful...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez okay, it's enough. Thank you.

Comment: While there probably someone here who can answer this as-is, and even I know what you mean, you should know that physics has frozen a decades-old definition of tensors that is not really used by mathematicians anymore. They do use this notation, but the answer you get from a physicist will be different than one you get from a mathematician.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez better if we also comment this. I have the following Ricci tensor, and the following metric (see question updapted). How can I find $R^{ij}$ using matrices product? Thank you

Comment: @MattSamuel okay, good. Thank you. I have uptapted the question with an example...

Comment: In my first comment I wrote the formula for raising indices for *any* tensor of the form $T_{i,j}$, and it of course applies also to the Ricci tensor… You therefore have $R^{i,j}=R_{k,l}g^{k,i}g^{l,j}$, with sums over repeated indices.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes, I Know. My doubt is if the matrix $g^{ki}$ is the same than $g^{l,j}$. Is it possible to do this operation using matrices or is only possible with sums?

Comment: This looks like a multiplication of matrices, but it is not, really. I'd say that it is better *not* to mix things. On the other hand, yes, the matrix $(g^{i,j})$ is the same as the matrix $(g^{k,l})$ and the matrix $(g^{r,s})$. The indices only serve to index things, much as the name of the variable in an integral is irrelevant, and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is the same thing as $\int_0^1f(t)dt$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez so I will remember: do not  multiply matrices to operate with tensors. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the rule of [raising and lowering indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices)? See answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $T_{ij}$ and $T^{ij}$ are *not* tensors, strictly speaking. They are respectively the covariant coordinates and contravariant coordinates of the same second-order tensor $\boldsymbol{T}$ on the chosen basis $\lbrace\boldsymbol{e}_i\rbrace$  of the vector space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$). Let us introduce $\lbrace\boldsymbol{e}^j\rbrace$, the dual basis of $\lbrace\boldsymbol{e}_i\rbrace$. On the one hand, using the Einstein summation convention [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)] and the rule of raising and lowering indices [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices)], we write
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{T} &= T_{i j} \left(\boldsymbol{e}^i \otimes \boldsymbol{e}^j\right) \\
&= T_{i j} \left( (g^{ik}\, \boldsymbol{e}_k) \otimes (g^{j\ell }\, \boldsymbol{e}_\ell )\right) ,
\end{aligned}
where $g^{ij}$ are the contravariant coordinates of the metric tensor.
On the other hand, we write $\boldsymbol{T} = T^{k \ell} \left(\boldsymbol{e}_k \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_\ell\right)$. By unicity of the contravariant coordinates of $\boldsymbol{T}$, we obtain the relationship
$$
T^{k \ell} = g^{ik}\, g^{j\ell}\, T_{i j}  \, .
$$
A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2467416/418542).

Since $v_i = g_{ij}\, v^j$ and $v^j = g^{ji}\, v_i$ for every vector $\boldsymbol{v}$, one has the matrix relation $[g_{ij}] = [g^{ij}]^{-1}$.